# Python multiprocessing hangs with custom module imported

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have to do a large number of calculations on data in an instance of a class, I currently have a loop running for each calculation, but it is taking infeasibly long (+50 hours).

So I wanted to try parallel processing, from what I have read I should be using the multiproccessing module and not the thread module as the task is CPU bound, but I can't get it working.

I can get multiple worker processes running on simple tasks but as soon as I import any custom modules, the script just hangs when I call pool.map.

Instead of pasting my actual code, I have written a dummy script that has the same issues. Please see below.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

# CUSTOM MODULES AND CLASS
import customModule as cm
from customObjectModule import CustomObject


def function(customObj, a):

    temp1 = cm.HelperClass2(customObj.data1)
    temp2 = cm.HelperClass1() * customObj.data2
    return temp1 * temp2 * a

def main():
    # Creating instance of custom object
    cObj = CustomObject(1,2)
    # using partial to deal with multiple arguments    
    partialF = partial(function,cObj)

    p = Pool(3)
    # running function, being passed the custom object and 
    # and running it for a set of inputs a
    print(p.map(partialF,[1,2,3]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not really sure why it isn't working,

I am also a relative novice when it comes to python. If anyone could point to an error in the above code, or point me towards some good resources explaining a bit more about multiprocessing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if replacing `p.map` by simply `map`, does it work? And usually, pool object should close and join at the end, though it seems not the cause of your problem.

Comment: By replacing p.map with map, aren't you just running them all on the process? It does work perfectly when I do that, but there is no speed increase at all. 

Are you saying that I should add p.close() and p.join() after the p.map()

Comment: 1. just assure that the program works for single process.  2. yes, add `p.close()` and `p.join()` after `p.map()`. Sorry, this might not help you solve it.

Comment: Yeah, didn't seem to help. Thanks though :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see anything wrong in your code yet. A suggestion is making your example code run-able, so people can repeat your problem in their own computer and may better understand what happened behind the bug. And you may already know, every editing will pop-up the question in time line, this will make more people see it.